# Container for embedding and scrolling child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a number of horizontal `HTMLElement`s that are in sum wider than the viewport.

Now I would like to have a container, which contains all of them and which I can tell to move one of these `HTMLElement`s into view (via *Javascript*). The default behavior should be `overflow: hidden`.

Is there already some kind of widget out there that handles this?
It may very well utilize *JQuery*, since I use it already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the plugin [jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: Great but I don't want a scroll container.

Comment: What do you mean? Your question says you want a container and want to be able to scroll that container programmatically.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear. I want the display the underlying element, but only programatically and not enable scrolling by the user.

Comment: With scrollTo you can set `overflow: hidden` easily enough, disabling user scrolling. Maybe draw a diagram or something to illustrate your idea? What you're describing still sounds like scrollTo.